# Regex inquiry or a music transposition function

Tags: javascript, regex, audio

I'm creating a function that is going to show to correct music chord according to a progression written in degrees.

I have this function:

```
    function transpose(accord, tonOrg, tonDest) {
var scales = {  
"GammeDeg": ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "#I", "#II", "#III", "#IV", "#V", "#VI", "#VII", "bI", "bII", "bIII", "bIV", "bV", "bVI", "bVII", "*I", "*II", "*III", "*IV", "*V", "*VI", "*VII", "bbI", "bbII", "bbIII", "bbIV", "bbV", "bbVI", "bbVII"],
"GammeC": ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb"],
"GammeG": ["G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb"],
"GammeD": ["D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "Db", "Eb", "F", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb"],
"GammeA": ["A", "B", "C#", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb"],
"GammeE": ["E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "Eb", "F", "G", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D#*", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db"],
"GammeB": ["B", "C#", "D#", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "Bb", "C", "D", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B*", "C#*", "D#*", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "A#*", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab"],
"GammeF#": ["F#", "G#", "A#", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#*", "G#*", "A#*", "B*", "C#*", "D#*", "E#*", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb"],
"GammeC#": ["C#", "D#", "E#", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#*", "D#*", "E#*", "F#*", "G#*", "A#*", "B#*", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb"],
"GammeG#": ["G#", "A#", "B#", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#*", "A#*", "B#*", "C#*", "D#*", "E#*", "F**", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F"],
"GammeD#": ["D#", "E#", "F*", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#*", "E#*", "F**", "G#*", "A#*", "B#*", "C**", "Db", "Eb", "F", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C"],
"GammeA#": ["A#", "B#", "C*", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "A", "B", "C#", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#*", "B#*", "C**", "D#*", "E#*", "F**", "G**", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D#", "Eb", "F", "G"],
"GammeF": ["F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbbb", "Cbb", ,"Dbb", ,"Ebb"],
"GammeBb": ["Bb", "C", "D", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "Bbbb", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abb"],
"GammeEb": ["Eb", "F", "G", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbb", "Dbb"],
"GammeAb": ["Ab", "Bb", "C", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbb", "Dbbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbb"],
"GammeDb": ["Db", "Eb", "F", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "Dbbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbbb", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbb"],
"GammeGb": ["Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "Gbbb", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbbb", "Dbbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb"]
};
var tonOrgGamme = scales["Gamme" + tonOrg];
var tonDestGamme = scales["Gamme" + tonDest];
var accordTranpose = accord.replace(/((("I"|"II"|"III"|"IV"|"V"|"VI"|"VII")#\*)|(("I"|"II"|"III"|"IV"|"V"|"VI"|"VII")#)|(("I"|"II"|"III"|"IV"|"V"|"VI"|"VII")b+)|(("I"|"II"|"III"|"IV"|"V"|"VI"|"VII")\**))/g, function(match) {
var i = tonOrgGamme.indexOf(match)
return tonDestGamme[i]
})
return accordTranpose
};
```

So if I send "I" to be transposed in C, the function will return C. If I send "V7" to be transposed in C, the result will be G7. I want only the degree in Roman numerals to be changed and whatever is after be kept the same and I'm not sure what to write in Regex for that.

Comment: Can you phrase your question by showing several input examples and their expected outputs?  This is how most regex people on the site would be thinking.

Comment: transpose("IVmaj7", "Deg", "F") would output "Bbmaj7"
    transpose("IIm9", "Deg", "Ab") would output "Bbm9"
    transpose("V13#5", "Deg", "C") would output "G13#5"
    transpose("III", "Deg", "Eb") would output "G"

Comment: Regex may not the best tool for this problem, at least not pure regex.  It looks like a switch statement might work better.

Comment: How could I just change the degree (only the Roman Numeral) but keep the rest identical ? I need to precise that the function might get an input like transpose("IVmaj7#11/VI", "Deg", "D") which would return "Gmaj7#11/B", if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be hard. First, you'll need to parse the user input into parts `userKeySignature`, `userChordQuality`, and `userNashvilleNumber` from the input (you do that). Next, find the chord index. But to do that, you first need to get the key, nashville number (roman numeral) find out the real number, zero-based.

Once you have that real number, a `keys` object/array structure will make it easier to get the root of the desired chord.

```
let keys = {
  c: ['c', 'd', …]
};
```

If you can have `"C"` as the user-selected key, you can use `keys[userSelectedKey.toLowerCase()]`

Next, you need to find the Chord Name from the Nashville number. That has two problems. The first, is that the nashville number is a roman numeral. The second problem is that it's one-based, not zero-based (Arrays are zero-based). But we can fix this by using an object or array. I've used array here.

```
let nashvilleNumbers = ['I', "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII"];
```

Next, find the chord index:

```
var chordIndex = nashvilleNumbers.indexOf(userNashvilleNumber);
```

Now that you know where the chord is in the array, you only have to select the key, but you parsed and checked that already from `userKeySignature`, right?

```
  var selectedKey = keys[userKeySignature];
  var selectedRoot = selectedKey[chordIndex];
```

Output should be `selectedRoot + userChordQuality`;

Always verify user input. This code is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I understand what your saying but I don't think it fills what I'm trying to achieve. The function I wrote works perfectly for transposing from one key to they other if I change the var accordTranpose part by

`var accordTranpose = accord.replace(/(([CDEFGAB]#\*)|([CDEFGAB]#)|([CDEFGAB]b+)|([CDEFGAB]\**))/g, function(match) {
    var i = tonOrgGamme.indexOf(match)
    return tonDestGamme[i]
})`

But I can't seem to find a way to change the regex to fit with I II III IV V and so on. III in C would give me CCC and IV in C would give me CG instead of E and F

Comment: I also want it to change chords with different bass notes than the root. For example VIm/III would return Am/E in C. It works perfectly from key to key with my function but I'm trying to making it work from the degrees (Nashville numbers) to any key.

Comment: By using variables instead of regex patterns, it's clearer and also easier to debug.